# Switch between Headset and Earpiece

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

Here what I want to do in the app:

When I'm having a phone call on my android device, I want to use the audio jack to send the call's audio to a circuit to do some processing on it.
At the same time, I want to have the caller's voice through device's earpiece so that I can talk to him.

I can switch between a wired headphone and device's speaker using audioManager, but haven't had any luck in turning on the earpiece so far.

I've also thought about recording and playing back the audio in real-time, but couldn't use the device's headset (earpiece).

Also I couldn't do anything about playing audio through two outputs at the same time.

1. How can I switch between Headset and Earpiece (device's headset)
   programmatically?
2. How is it possible to send audio out of android device through 2
   device at the same time?

I want to use this app on devices having android API above 15.

Comment: are you solved it?

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev no. i gave up on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it is impossible to produce audio out of two audio ports at the same time. The AudioFlinger (android audio server implementation) is designed to run on a single thread, and it may not even be allowed by most devices HAL. This is also why when you listen to audio through your headphones, the music is interrupted by notifications sounds playing through your phone's speaker. Only one can be producing audio at once.

I would recommend that you just send the call out of the audio port. You can set up this piece of hardware that you mentioned to both do its processing and play the audio out of a small speaker.